# How do I fix KeyError bug in my code while implementing K-Nearest Neighbours from scratch?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, knn

I am trying to implement K-Nearest Neighbours algorithm from scratch in Python. The code I wrote worked well for the `Breast-Cancer-Wisconsin.csv` dataset.
However, the same code when I try to run for *Iris.csv* dataset, my implementation fails and gives KeyError.

The only difference in the 2 datasets is the fact that in `Breast-Cancer-Wisconsin.csv` there are only 2 classes ('2' for malignant and '4' for benign) and both the labels are integers wheres in `Iris.csv` there are 3 classes ('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica') and all these 3 labels are in string type.

Here is the code I wrote (for `Iris.csv`) :

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from collections import Counter
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import random

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

dataset = {'k':[[1,2],[2,3],[3,1]], 'r':[[6,5],[7,7],[8,6]]}
new_features = [5,7]

#[[plt.scatter(j[0],j[1], s=100, color=i) for j in dataset[i]] for i in dataset]
#plt.scatter(new_features[0], new_features[1], s=100)
#plt.show()

def k_nearest_neighbors(data, predict, k=3):
    if len(data) >= k:
        warnings.warn('K is set to a value less than total voting groups!')

    distances = []

    for group in data:
        for features in data[group]:
            euclidean_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(features) - np.array(predict))
            distances.append([euclidean_distance, group])

    votes = [i[1] for i in sorted(distances)[:k]]
    vote_result = Counter(votes).most_common(1)[0][0]

    return vote_result

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)

#full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()
#random.shuffle(full_data)

test_size = 0.2
train_set = {'setosa':[], 'versicolor':[], 'virginica':[]}
test_set = {'setosa':[], 'versicolor':[], 'virginica':[]}

train_data = full_data[:-int(test_size*len(full_data))]
test_data = full_data[-int(test_size*len(full_data)):]

for i in train_data:
    train_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

for i in test_data:
    test_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

correct = 0
total = 0

for group in test_set:
    for data in test_set[group]:
        vote = k_nearest_neighbors(train_set, data, k=5)
        if group == vote:
            correct += 1
        total += 1

print('Accuracy : ', correct/total)
```

When I run the above code, I get a `KeyError` message at line number 49.

Could anyone please explain to me where I am going wrong? Also, it would be great if someone could point out how do I modify this algorithm to classify multiple classes (instead of 2 or 3) in the future?

Also, how do I handle if the classes are in string type instead of integer?

*one solution I thought of was to convert all string types to integer types and try to solve but would that work?*

**REFERENCES**

[Iris.csv](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris)

[Breas-Cancer-Wisconsin.csv](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+(original))

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from your last question:

> one solution I thought of was to convert all string types to integer types and try to solve but would that work?

Yes, that would work. You shouldn't have to hardcode the names of all the classes of every problem in your code. Instead, you can just write a function that reads all the different values for the class attribute, and assigns a numeric value to each different one.

> Could anyone please explain to me where I am going wrong?

Most likely, the problem is that you are reading an instance whose class attribute is not `'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'` (something like `Iris-setosa` perhaps?). The idea above should fix this problem.

> Also, it would be great if someone could point out how do I modify this algorithm to classify multiple classes (instead of 2 or 3) in the future?

As discuss before, you just need to avoid hard-coding the names of the classes in your code

> Also, how do I handle if the classes are in string type instead of integer?

```
def get_class_values(data):

    classes_seen = {}
    for i in data:
       _class = data[-1]
       if _class not in classes_seen:
           classes_seen[_class] = len(classes_seen)

    return classes_seen
```

A function like this one would return a mapping between all your classes (no matter the type) and numeric codes (from 0 to N-1). Using this mapping would also solve all the problems mentioned before.

Comment: Yes that would work. Thanks for the answer. However I found an even simpler solution and I have posted it as answer below.

Comment: No, I checked the CSV file before I used it in my algorithm. All instances are named as 'Setosa' , 'Virginica' , 'Versicolor' . So the error is not because of the iris-setosa or differently named instances. In fact the error was a subtle bug, the solution to which I have posted below and explained in the best way I could. Do let me know if my answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert String Labels In CSV Files To Integer Labels**

After going through some GitHub repos I came across a very simple yet elegant piece of code that solves the above problem. Hope it helps those who have faced this problem before (beginners especially!)

```
% read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

% clean the data file
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)

% convert the string classes into integer types.
% integers are assigned from 0 to N-1.
% species is the name of the column which has class labels.

df['species'] = df['species'].astype('category')
df['species_value'] = df['species'].cat.codes
df.drop(['species'], 1, inplace=True)

% convert the data frame to list
full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()
random.shuffle(full_data)
```

**Post Debugging**

Turns out that we need not use the above piece of code also, i.e I can get the answer without explicitly converting the string labels into integer labels (using the above code).

I have posted the original code after some minor changes (below) and the key error is now fixed. Also, I am now getting an accuracy of 97% to 100% (only on IRIS dataset).

```
test_size = 0.2
train_set = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[]}
test_set = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[]}
```

That is the only change you need to make to the original code I posted in order to make it work!! Simple!

However, please note that the numbers have to be given as integers and not string (otherwise it would lead to key error!).

**Wrap-Up**

There are some commented lines in the original code which I thought would be good to explain in case somebody ran into some issues. Here's one snippet with the comments removed (compare with original code in the question).

```
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)

full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()
random.shuffle(full_data)
```

Here's the output you get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'virginica'

*What went wrong?*

Note that here we did not convert the string labels into integer labels. Therefore, when we tried to convert the data in the CSV to float values, the kernel threw an error because a string cannot be converted to float!

So one way to go about it is that you don't convert the data into floating point values and then you won't get this error. However in many cases you need to convert all the data into floating point (for eg.. normalisation, accuracy, long mathematical calculations, prevention of loss of precision etc etc..).

Hence after heavy debugging and going through a lot of articles I finally came up with a simple version of the original code (below):

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from collections import Counter
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import random

def k_nearest_neighbors(data, predict, k=3):
    if len(data) >= k:
        warnings.warn('K is set to a value less than total voting groups!')

    distances = []

    for group in data:
        for features in data[group]:
            euclidean_distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(features) - np.array(predict))
            distances.append([euclidean_distance, group])

    votes = [i[1] for i in sorted(distances)[:k]]
    vote_result = Counter(votes).most_common(1)[0][0]

    return vote_result

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)

df['species'] = df['species'].astype('category')
df['species_value'] = df['species'].cat.codes
df.drop(['species'], 1, inplace=True)

full_data = df.astype(float).values.tolist()
random.shuffle(full_data)

test_size = 0.2
train_set = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[]}
test_set = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[]}

train_data = full_data[:-int(test_size*len(full_data))]
test_data = full_data[-int(test_size*len(full_data)):]

for i in train_data:
    train_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

for i in test_data:
    test_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

correct = 0
total = 0

for group in test_set:
    for data in test_set[group]:
        vote = k_nearest_neighbors(train_set, data, k=5)
        if group == vote:
            correct += 1
        total += 1

print('Accuracy : ', (correct/total)*100,'%')
```

*Hope this helps!*